# Do, inner and outer functions get their own copy of same variable?

Tags: javascript, closures

just a bit confused by this code

```
var counter = function() {
    //...
    var count = 0;
    return function () {
        return count = count + 1;
    } 
}

var nextValue = counter();  
console.log(nextValue());
nextValue.count = 7;
console.log(nextValue());
console.log(nextValue.count);
console.log(nextValue());
```

Output is

```
1
2
7
3
```

It's counter intuitive.  There are two representations of count.  One on the outerfunction nextValue and one that only the inner anonymous function can see.

Correct, or are my missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `nextValue.count` does **not** refer to the local variable "count" declared inside the function. It is not possible, in fact, to create a reference to a variable local to a function from code outside the function. What you're referencing there is simply a property of the function object.

So, yes, the "count" variable that the returned function has access to is effectively completely private to that function, and it is persisted in the closure formed by the call to the "counter" function.

If you *did* want that to work, you could do this:

```
function counter() {
  function actual() {
    return actual.count = actual.count + 1;
  }
  actual.count = 0;
  return actual;
}
```

*edit* — (fixed bogus code) the name "actual" inside gives the returned function safe access to the function object itself; originally I typed "this" there, and that would not work unless the external code set it up explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

The way you describe it, `count` is effectively a private variable. When you're assign to `nextValue.count`, you're creating a separate property--not accessing the internal `count` being incremented by your counter.